# can't run simplest examples in ggmap::qmplot (error: no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "NULL")

Tags: r, r-raster, ggmap

I am trying to rebuild some old lecture notes and can't get the most basic examples of `ggmap::qmplot()` to work - I'm guessing they may have been broken by recent updates to the `raster` package? (I have tried the latest CRAN version of `ggmap`, dated 2019-02-05, as well as a fresh `remotes::install_github(dkahle/ggmap)`).

This example is straight from `?qmplot` (but not run in testing in order to conserve check time ... !)

```r
library(ggmap)
qmplot(lon, lat, data = crime)
## <lines denoting downloading of stamen tiles>
```

> Error in UseMethod("as.raster") :  no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "NULL"

On the other hand, I don't see `raster` (I have version 3.4-13, dated 2021-06-15) anywhere in the list of loaded packages??

I suspect this belongs on the [ggmap issues list](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues) but thought I would ask here first in case someone has already run across/solved/worked around this, or I'm doing something silly.

---

**Update/results of further archaeology:** an object created via `expand.grid()` → `lapply(split(., seq(nrow(.)), ...)` → `plyr::ldply` is missing a `.id` field because the list created by `lapply` is nameless. I don't understand why this *ever* worked, because (1) `expand.grid()` always returns a data frame; (2) `split()` on a matrix returns a named list while `split()` on a data frame returns an unnamed list ... I can't imagine these behaviours changing in R without my noticing??

I fixed this by [patching a fork](https://github.com/bbolker/ggmap/commit/bb17c2d6e0b77d7ab2126d24d573fe018666bef2) but would really like to understand what broke (and whether it is something peculiar to me ...)

---

```r
other attached packages:
[1] ggmap_3.0.0.903 ggplot2_3.3.5  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6          pillar_1.6.1        compiler_4.2.0     
 [4] plyr_1.8.6          tools_4.2.0         bitops_1.0-7       
 [7] digest_0.6.27       lifecycle_1.0.0     tibble_3.1.2       
[10] gtable_0.3.0        lattice_0.20-44     pkgconfig_2.0.3    
[13] png_0.1-7           rlang_0.4.11        DBI_1.1.1          
[16] curl_4.3.2          withr_2.4.2         dplyr_1.0.7        
[19] httr_1.4.2          stringr_1.4.0       RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3
[22] generics_0.1.0      vctrs_0.3.8         grid_4.2.0         
[25] tidyselect_1.1.1    glue_1.4.2          R6_2.5.0           
[28] jpeg_0.1-8.1        fansi_0.5.0         sp_1.4-5           
[31] tidyr_1.1.3         purrr_0.3.4         magrittr_2.0.1     
[34] scales_1.1.1        ellipsis_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.1   
[37] colorspace_2.0-2    utf8_1.2.1          stringi_1.6.2      
[40] munsell_0.5.0       crayon_1.4.1
```

Comment: I tried this by downloading from the github and set the option 3 for none of the package to update.  It is working for me in `R 4.1.0` though ` qmplot(lon, lat, data = crime)
Using zoom = 7...
Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL.
Warning message:
Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_point). `

Comment: My `packageVersion('raster')#
[1] ‘3.4.10’`

Comment: I'm still digging.  I think there might be a `plyr`/`dplyr` thing going on ... it's failing after an `arrange()` call. (plyr 1.8.6, dplyr 1.0.7)

Comment: Huh. I was able to make it work by [patching my fork](https://github.com/bbolker/ggmap/commit/bb17c2d6e0b77d7ab2126d24d573fe018666bef2) to make sure that a list created by `lapply(split(tilesNeeded, 1:nrow(tilesNeeded)), ...)` was named. I have r-devel 2021-06-11 r80482 ... wondering what happened here??

Comment: The `as.raster` method used probably has the `ANY` signature --- that is, it uses the `grDevices` package, not the `raster` package.